# Using Webpack to require revealing modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've just started looking into all the fancy stuff Javascript has to offer mainly `Webkit`. I've got a decent sized application which uses the revealing module pattern. These modules make calls to public functions of other modules to make calculations and return results.

Using this pattern was working great until I started to contemplate having dozens of script includes in my html pages. So, here we are...

For the purposes of the question, I have made a much simpler application to demonstrate what is going wrong for me.

I have two javascript modules contained within their own files:

```
// one.js 
require("babel-loader?two!./two.js"); 
var one = (function(){
  two.sayHello(); 
})() 

// two.js
var two = (function(){
  var sayHello = function(){
    console.log('Hello World'); 
  }
  return {
    sayHello: sayHello
  }
})()
```

What I'm trying to do is use `sayHello` function from `two.js` within `one.js`.

So, firstly, I installed `Webpack` and `exports-loader` and created the following configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js', 
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,

        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'] 
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`index.js` is my entry file and simply includes the following single line:

```
require('./one.js');
```

Now, when trying to run this code, I'm getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: two is not defined

With a little more digging, I found that my compiled `bundle.js` file was throwing the following Error when trying to import `two.js`:

> throw new Error("Module parse failed: \testing_env\webpack\two.js
>   'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (2:2)\nYou may
>   need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Obviously i'm doing something wrong, I'm just not sure what. I've tried both `exports-loader` and `babel-loader` but with no joy.

**Which loader should I be using to parse module dependencies?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box webpack has support for [CommonJS](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html) *(which is the same module system that [Nodejs implements](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html))*. This means that you need to use the **require/export** syntax to make use of the modules.

To export something in a module you simply do:

```
// a.js
function a() { console.log("I'm a module '); }

module.exports = a;
```

and in your other module you do:

```
// b.js
const a = require('./a.js');

a(); // I'm a module
```

`require()` will simply returns the `exports` object. Whatever you put on it you will be able to retrieve in another module.

This is why webpack is a module bundler, it comes with a built in module system. The revelaing module pattern is more practical if you load your JS files directly in the browser without a module bundler, and you want to incapsulate your data (in "modules").

The [Revelaing module pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) is useful when you don't have a module system and you simply load up your JS files in the browser. Till recenlty when ES Modules were introduced in the browser, JavaScript didn't have a module system of it's own. This is why people came up with the module pattern, to have a way to incapsulate logic in the browser. But now because of tools like webpack and now we have natively the [ES Modules](https://pawelgrzybek.com/native-ecmascript-modules-in-the-browser/) system, we can have a more better way to incapsulate our logic.

Does this make sense?

Comment: What if I have multiple functions I want to export from a? Can you show an example of that please

Comment: like I said in my post, whatever you put on `module.exports` that is what you will get when you `require()` it in another module. To export multiple functions you simply do `module.exports.fn1 = ...; module.exports.fn2 = ...` Then you will require() an obejct with all the functions you exported. `const fn1 = require('./a').fn1;`